# shopify liquid and jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

I have a pretty simple code to display certain text based on if the product variant is more than $50 and Shopify is not responding to my jQuery.

Here's the HTML:

```
<p class="orders-50 orders-50-over">This item ships for free!</p>
<p class="orders-50 orders-50-under">Orders of $50or more ship for free.</p>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
if (product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price >= 5000) {
    jQuery('.orders-50-over').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    jQuery('.orders-50-under').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  } else {
    jQuery('.orders-50-over').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    jQuery('.orders-50-under').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
  }
```

Although I'm not a jQuery expert,I thought this code would work. The classes are not changing when I select different product variants. They aren't even showing up.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what event did you bind this function to? you need to bind this jQuery snippet to click event or change event so this script will get executed. Check out the following link to see how you bind to change event. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got this one solved by binding it with a .change to a select.